# Rate Limit Twitter Tweepy

Tags: twitter, cursor, tweepy

I'm using the Twitter API to collect tweets with access through the Academic Research Developer account. I've been trying to pull tweets using the API Search Full Archive feature of Tweepy and read that there is a rate limit of 300 tweets/15 mins. In practice, however, this does not seem to be the case, as I was able to pull ~6000 tweets over a couple minutes before getting a rate limit error. After 15 minutes, I don't see any reset and cannot pull another batch of tweets.

I was wondering whether anyone knows how the rate limit actually works, so that I can better understand how to design my program. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was curious about this a short while ago, and took a stab after reading some other posts on here to determine rate limit / its consumption.

Here's what I have for you (assuming you are using tweepy).

```
print(api.rate_limit_status()['resources'])
```

gives you all the rate limits for your  set up. If you are curious specifically around searches, you can leverage this. I took the liberty to drop in the one I built, feel free to modify it to your liking.

```
print("Searches Remaining: ", api.rate_limit_status()['resources']['search']['/search/tweets']['remaining'],
      "/" ,api.rate_limit_status()['resources']['search']['/search/tweets']['limit'],"")
```

In my case, it looks like this right now. Searches Remaining:  162 / 180

If you choose to play around with it, and peel it back a bit, you will see the JSON payload containing this in the search section (it is a total of over 1400 lines)

```
"search": {
        "/search/tweets": {
            "limit": 180,
            "remaining": 162,
            "reset": 1660874618
        }
```

Hope this helps!